# What the f***, internet!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Another one of my rhyming riddles:

> "WTF!" will you scream,
>       what you seek, it may well seem,
>       it's there not, was it a dream?
>       If that now was just a slumber,
>       can you tell me what's my number?

Enjoy :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Could it be a

> 404 error page?

*"WTF!" will you scream,*
*what you seek, it may well seem,*
*it's there not, was it a dream?*

> It's so annoying not to find the webpage you seek. Maybe it never existed?

*If that now was just a slumber,*
*can you tell me what's my number?*

> Your number is 404.

Comment: WTF! I am getting too easy XD

Comment: @Noldor I've solved a riddle with this same answer before ... can't find it again now, but it was definitely somewhere on this site.

Comment: You're talking about [this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/984547312), right?

Comment: @BaSzAt No, I found it - it was [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ).

Comment: @randal'thor that was a dirty trick!